# Switching between two UINavigationControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Let's say I have two navigation stacks: one is for registration and login, the other is my main app.

On first-launch I'm going to show the registration and login stack and on completion transition to the main app stack. How can I switch between these two stacks smoothly?

Additionally, I'm going to show the main app stack and only present the login and register stack if the user signs out, so this one is clearer: just a `self.present` on the navigationcontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the navigation instance to

```
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!.rootViewController = // main or register stack
```

---

Actually you don't have to use 2 stacks it would be 1 and use it for push/pop appropriately , but while you do the login/home transitions do

```
// this will clear all controllers from the stack and set only the assigned one 
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([mainVC/loginVC],animated:true)
```

Comment: Is there a way to smoothly transition between the two? This will just abruptly change the view on display right?

Comment: Does this mean I need one primary navigation controller above all my other navigation controllers?

Comment: you need only 1 navigationcontroller no nested ones

Comment: I have different styling– so for example my login controller animates a flow across 3 screens on present. However my main VC is a pageviewcontroller with 3 sections.

Comment: this is related to the segue configuration between the vcs having multiple navigations won't make a difference